# how to make a real graph from data from tsv or csv file

Tags: android-studio

I would like a java code in android studio like formula for storing data from a tsv or a csv file and making a real graph.Specifically storing ecg data and everytime i would like to change the data file i could make a graph.

Comment: Welcome Ermina. Read How to [Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that please show some effort. What have you tried? What didn't work.

Comment: @Ermina: Please go through guideline to post the question. Also mentioned what are the steps you followed to achieve expected behaviour and where you stuck. if you post the little bit of code it will be easy to understand. Please try to add more tags so that question get easily categoriesd

Comment: I would like a java code that makes a real graph from ecg data in andoid studio, like a electrocardiography.